# AWK use gsub under condition

Tags: awk, conditional-statements, gsub

I have a question about gsub of part string if condition match....

INPUT (tab delimited)

```
a  b  a////l&&o c
a  c  d////p&&v c
c  o  a////p&&v z
```

OUTPUT

```
a  b  alo c
a  c  dpv c
c  o  a////p&&v z
```

I am trying to use:

> awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if($1=="a"){gsub(////,"",$3);gsub(&&,"",$3)
>   print $0; else print $0}}' INPUT

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$1=="a"{gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)} 1'  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk '{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)}} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per OP's request adding it like:"

```
awk '{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3);print $0} else {print $0}} 1' Input_file
```

In case your Input_file is TAB delimited then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1=="a"{gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)} 1' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)}} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per OP's request:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3);print $0} else {print $0}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: And is it possible to write it with if else if else statement?

Comment: @Vonton, Like this? `awk '{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)}} 1' Input_file` OR `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3)}} 1' Input_file`

Comment: I ment something like  awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{if($1=="a"){gsub(/\/+|&+/,"",$3) print $0; else print $0}' but it doesn't work with this syntax

Comment: @Vonton, Please check mine 2nd OR now?

Comment: Great work, it works. I used bad {} and ; . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

another way with awk:

```
awk -F'[/&]' -v OFS="" '/^a/{$1=$1}7' file
```

The idea is, we use `/ or &` as `FS`, if a line starts with `a`, we do `$1=$1` so that the FS will be replaced by OFS in output. Otherwise we just print the line with the original FS characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1=="a"{gsub(/[\/&]/,"",$3)}1' file > outfile
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/qoAu2S):

```
s="a    b   a////l&&o   c
a   c   d////p&&v   c
c   o   a////p&&v   z"
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1=="a"{gsub(/[\/&]/,"",$3)}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
a   b   alo c
a   c   dpv c
c   o   a////p&&v   z
```

**Details**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` - set input/output field separator to a tab char
- `$1=="a"`  - if Field 1 value is `a`
- `{gsub(/[\/&]/,"",$3)}` - replace each `/` and `&` with an empty string in Field 3
- `1` - default print action.